# How to type (id="post - <?php the_ID ();?>") in the CSS file?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I would like to modify the size of posts in Wordpress Theme.

When I edit it like this

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('thumb'); ?> style="width: 250px;">
```

The result is good, but I can not type `@media` in this case.
Is there a way to modify the size through a CSS file?

Comment: The size? Is this attribute specific to this element, or can you use a class to set it for multiple elements at once?

Comment: PHP wont be processed in css files. You can use a class .postSize and change it based on screen size using media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Give your post a class in CSS file

for example

**my_style.css** file

```
@media screen {
    .my-post {
       # style goes here
    }

}
```

then import the file with within `<head></head>` tag

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_style.css"> // put the correct path
```

then in php/html file use

```
<div class="my-post">
```

Classes can be applied to multiple elements within the html document

if you want to use id then the rule should be

`[id^=post]` it will take all id that starts with "post" string

**my_style.css** file

```
@media screen {
    [id^=post] { 
       # style goes here
    }

}
```